# CS-Studio 4.4.1, Debian 10, Startup errors: org.csstudio.logging.PluginLogListener (logging) - Unable to acquire PluginConverter for several jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, debian, corba

As a beginner on CS-Studio (CSS) / Eclipse, I've been struggling with how exactly to install/deploy/implement those jar files correctly, in such a way that CSS can run smoothly. So, funny stuff: if I simply start CSS, I get the following errors:

```
SEVERE [Thread 34] org.csstudio.logging.PluginLogListener (logging) - Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for: /home/cs-studio-snapshot/cs-studio/plugins/orb-master.
SEVERE [Thread 34] org.csstudio.logging.PluginLogListener (logging) - Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for: /home/cs-studio-snapshot/cs-studio/plugins/maven-osgi-bundles-master.
SEVERE [Thread 34] org.csstudio.logging.PluginLogListener (logging) - Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for: /home/cs-studio-snapshot/cs-studio/plugins/TangORB-javacommon-jacorb_free-0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar.
SEVERE [Thread 34] org.csstudio.logging.PluginLogListener (logging) - Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for: /home/cs-studio-snapshot/cs-studio/plugins/maven-osgi-repository-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.
SEVERE [Thread 34] org.csstudio.logging.PluginLogListener (logging) - Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for: /home/cs-studio-snapshot/cs-studio/plugins/glassfish-corba-omgapi-4.2.4-javadoc.jar.
SEVERE [Thread 34] org.csstudio.logging.PluginLogListener (logging) - Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for: /home/cs-studio-snapshot/cs-studio/plugins/TangORB-jacorb_free-0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar.
SEVERE [Thread 34] org.csstudio.logging.PluginLogListener (logging) - Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for: /home/cs-studio-snapshot/cs-studio/plugins/apache-maven-3.8.1.
SEVERE [Thread 34] org.csstudio.logging.PluginLogListener (logging) - Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for: /home/cs-studio-snapshot/cs-studio/plugins/glassfish-corba-omgapi-4.2.4-sources.jar.
```

However, if I add the Maven `bin` folder to the PATH environment variable *before* starting CSS, I get no errors whatsoever.

These `.jar` files are inside the `plugins` folder in the cs-studio installation directory. So I assumed they are 'operational'.

At the same time, there are some hidden folders `.../default/.metadata/.plugins/*` for some of those classes in my CSS project workspace. Most of them simply contains a `desktop.ini` file. (Actually I got this workspace from a previous colleague already with the required plugins. Though I believe some others are required).

I believe the Maven bin path could be set in some ini or settings file from CSS, though I don't know which one or where.

Or does anyone know a better way how to tackle these issues?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a ticket within the csstudio github repo, someone there will more likely see it and be able to help you.